Simplifying matrix inequality
In a constrained optimization problem I encounter: how to solve for $\lambda$ in
$$\frac{1}{2}f^T (B+\lambda A)^{-1}A(B+\lambda A)^{-1}f \leq 1$$
where $A,B,f$ are known; and $A, B$ are symmetric and positive-definite; and to be explicit, $A, B$ are $n \times n$ matrices, and $f$ is $n \times 1$ vector.
Any clever way to manipulate the expression to “solve” for $\lambda$ ? Namely, to get an explicit inequality on $\lambda$? Thanks much!

I don't know if this is quite what you're after, but you can cast this condition as a (not quite linear) matrix inequality. In particular, you can write this inequality as
$$
2 - f^T (B+\lambda A)^{-1}A(B+\lambda A)^{-1}f \geq 0.
$$
The left-hand side of this inequality is the Schur complement of the upper-left block within the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{(B + \lambda A)A^{-1}(B + \lambda A) & f\\
f^T & 2}.
$$
So, your condition is equivalent to this (symmetric) block-matrix being positive semidefinite. Notably, taking $M = A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$, we can rewrite
$$
(B + \lambda A)A^{-1}(B + \lambda A) = \\
(A^{1/2}[M + \lambda I]A^{1/2})A^{-1}(A^{1/2}[M + \lambda I]A^{1/2}) = \\
A^{1/2}[M + \lambda I]^2A^{1/2},
$$
so your condition is equivalence to the positive definiteness of
$$
\pmatrix{A^{1/2}[M + \lambda I]^2A^{1/2} & f\\
f^T & 2}.
$$
With a matrix congruence, we see that this in turn is equivalent to the positive definiteness of
$$
\pmatrix{A^{-1/2}\\ & 1}\pmatrix{A^{1/2}[M + \lambda I]^2A^{1/2} & f\\
f^T & 2}\pmatrix{A^{-1/2}\\ & 1} = \\
\pmatrix{[M + \lambda I]^2 & A^{-1/2}f\\
(A^{-1/2}f)^T & 2}.
$$

From here, we can get an interesting necessary (but not sufficient) condition for inequality where we may "solve" for $\lambda$. That is, we can get a nice lower bound for $\lambda$.
If we consider the Schur complement of the lower-right block, we end up with the equivalent condition
$$
[M + \lambda I]^2 - \frac 12 A^{-1/2}ff^TA^{-1/2} \succeq 0 \implies\\
[M + \lambda I]^2 \succeq \underbrace{\frac 12 A^{-1/2}ff^TA^{-1/2}}_Q \implies\\
M + \lambda I \succeq \sqrt{Q} \implies\\
\lambda I \succeq \sqrt{Q} - M,
$$
where $\succeq$ denotes the Loewner order. In other words, we reach the conclusion that your condition implies that $\lambda$ is greater than or equal to the largest eigenvalue of $\sqrt{Q} - M$, where $Q = \frac 12 A^{-1/2}ff^TA^{-1/2}$. Notably, $Q$ is a symmetric positive definite rank-1 matrix, which means that its square root can be calculated with relative ease:
$$
\sqrt{Q} = \frac 1{\sqrt{\text{tr}(Q)}}Q,
$$
where we find that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(Q) = 
\operatorname{tr}\left(\frac 12 A^{-1/2}ff^TA^{-1/2}\right) = 
\frac 12 f^TA^{-1}f.
$$

Very interesting idea! Admittedly I was just warming up to it, and as I verify the steps numerically, it seems I have a gap: wonder how to reason about this step
$$ [M+\lambda I]^2 \geq Q \Longleftrightarrow M+\lambda \geq \sqrt{Q}$$ The sources I see haven't helped me move past it.. https://www.akshayagrawal.com/lecture-notes/html/loewner-order.html

@user1551 That's a good point. So $M + \lambda I \succeq \sqrt{Q}$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition for the original inequality

@boombeach As user1551 said, I actually made a bit of a mistake there. While I am able to get you a concrete lower bound for $\lambda$ in this way, I can't quite solve your inequality for $\lambda$.

@BenGrossmann reaching $(M+\lambda I)^2 \geq Q$ is helpful! Thanks still!
